# CSS grid has 'ghost' empty cells - where have they come from?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a list of 12 iframes that I would like to arrange into a 3 x 4 grid.

This is my code snippet that I'm trying to turn into a grid:

```
<p>
    <iframe 1></iframe>
    <br>
    <iframe 2></iframe>
    <br>
    <iframe 3></iframe>
    <br>
</p>
```

My attempt is:

```
#tab > div > div > p 
{
display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr ;
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
}
#tab > div > div > p iframe {
    width:100%;
}
```

However when I attempt to use CSS grid there appear to be 'ghost' empty child elements that populate between each iframe.

What is going on here?

Comment: Hi, chewflow. It's recommended to create code snippet which represents your problem. In your case, <br> elements is the reason of "ghost" empty childs. If you modify the question, I'll answer it.

Comment: Hi @userlond - yes apologies for omitting that! Have added it now. And now I see what you're saying about the <br>. It makes sense. Am unsure how to mitigate it though as I don't have control over the source code, just the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

According to your code there are some `<br>` in between each `iframe`, you may check your `for loop` render logic to see where they come from. The grid displays properly after remove all the `<br>`

By the way, the `display: grid` is now being applied to a `<p>` element, it is suggested to change it to `<div>` as well :)

Comment: Thank you :-) 

I don't have control over the source code, just the CSS so was hoping to find a workaround that works just via CSS..

Comment: you can hide the <br> elements: `br { display: none; }` but yet your iframes have fixed height so you will see empty space between each row. You can solve it by writing
`#tab-f49340a9-112e-0 > div > div > p iframe { 
height: auto; 
}`

Comment: Omg @SaraStoimenovska you're awesome, thank you ^_^